# Covariance and type inference in Scala

Tags: scala, type-inference, covariance

Given the code

```
object Renderer {

  sealed abstract class BasicRender

  case class RenderImages(img: Array[File]) extends BasicRender

  case class RenderVideo(video: File) extends BasicRender

  def rendererFor[T <: BasicRender : Manifest, Z <: Render.RenderingContext](ctx: Z): Option[Render[T]] = {
    val z = manifest[T].erasure
    if (z == classOf[RenderImages]) {
      Some(new ImagesRenderer(ctx.asInstanceOf[ImagesContext])) // .asInstanceOf[Render[T]])
    } else
    if (z == classOf[RenderVideo]) {
      Some(new VideoRenderer(ctx.asInstanceOf[VideoContext])) // .asInstanceOf[Render[T]])
    } else {
      None
    }
  }

  private class ImagesRenderer(ctx: ImagesContext) extends Render[RenderImages] {

    override def renderJSON(json: String)(implicit jsCtx: PhantomJsContext) = {
      None
    }

  }

  private class VideoRenderer(ctx: VideoContext) extends Render[RenderVideo] {

    override def renderJSON(json: String)(implicit jsCtx: PhantomJsContext) = {
      None
    }

  }


}

trait Render[+Out] {

  def renderJSON(json: String)(implicit jsCtx: PhantomJsContext): Option[Out]

}
```

I made Render trait covariant for it's type parameter, so if

```
RenderImages <: BasicRender
```

then

```
ImagesRenderer <: Render[RenderImages]
```

But it looks like the compiler is not able to infer the type of renderer in **rendererFor**, so I need to add explicit class casting like

```
Some(new ImagesRenderer(ctx.asInstanceOf[ImagesContext]).asInstanceOf[Render[T]])
```

what is wrong with my reasoning here?

Comment: Don't you mean `Render` where you say `Renderer` above?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral yes, corrected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained by Daniel C. Sobral, your problem here is that you are instantiating the different renderers dynamically, in a way that does not capture in the type system the relation between `ctx` and the result type of `rendererFor`.
One common way to solve this kind of issues is to use a *type class*:

```
import java.io.File

class PhantomJsContext

trait Renderer[+Out] {
  def renderJSON(json: String)(implicit jsCtx: PhantomJsContext): Option[Out]
}

trait RendererFactory[ContextType, ResultType] {
  def buildRenderer( ctx: ContextType ): Renderer[ResultType]
}

object Renderer {
  case class RenderImages(img: Array[File])
  case class RenderVideo(video: File)

  trait ImagesContext  
  trait VideoContext

  def rendererFor[ContextType, ResultType](ctx: ContextType)( implicit factory: RendererFactory[ContextType, ResultType] ): Renderer[ResultType] = {
    factory.buildRenderer( ctx )
  }

  class ImagesRenderer(ctx: ImagesContext) extends Renderer[RenderImages] {
    def renderJSON(json: String)(implicit jsCtx: PhantomJsContext) = ???
  }
  implicit object ImagesRendererFactory extends RendererFactory[ImagesContext, RenderImages] {
    def buildRenderer( ctx: ImagesContext ) = new ImagesRenderer( ctx )
  }

  class VideoRenderer(ctx: VideoContext) extends Renderer[RenderVideo] {
    def renderJSON(json: String)(implicit jsCtx: PhantomJsContext) = ???
  }
  implicit object VideoRendererFactory extends RendererFactory[VideoContext, RenderVideo] {
    def buildRenderer( ctx: VideoContext ) = new VideoRenderer( ctx )
  }
}
```

You can easily check in the REPL that the correct types are returned:

```
scala> lazy val r1 = Renderer.rendererFor( new Renderer.ImagesContext {} )
r1: Renderer[Renderer.RenderImages] = <lazy>

scala> :type r1
Renderer[Renderer.RenderImages]

scala> lazy val r2 = Renderer.rendererFor( new Renderer.VideoContext {} )
r2: Renderer[Renderer.RenderVideo] = <lazy>

scala> :type r2
Renderer[Renderer.RenderVideo]
```

Answer (score 5):

`T` is not to be inferred: it is a parameter that is passed to the method, and there isn't really any guarantee that what is being returned is an `Option[Render[T]]`. For instance, assume you pass `RenderImages` and it returns a `VideoRenderer`, then it would obviously be wrong.

Now, the `if` conditionals you put in there might prevent that from happening, but none of that is used by the compiler to figure out whether you are returning the right type or not.

Comment: You are spot on the reasons why it does not compile. However, I'd like to point that `manifest[T].erasure` is actually correct: the manifest is passed as a context bound.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles Damn, I missed the context bound! Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: so what is the preferred way to make it not happen? Does Scala support dependent types?

Comment: @jdevelop Scala does support dependent types, but its encoding is different from other languages. I think the solution presented by Régis answer is better, though.

Comment: Yes, I realized that if I have to pass the rendering context - then it's easy to go with the typeclass. Thanks for the help!